# save to local and S3 object store (efficiently)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-s3

I have an artifact that I would like to save to the local drive as well as to a S3 object store.  I suspect there might be a more efficient way to

1. write to the local drive (sync)
2. send a copy of the file to S3 (async)

I'm torn on how to use `dump` and `dumps` in a way that makes sense.

```py
// res can be any python type
with open(cachepath, 'wb') as f:
    logger.info("Writing results to cache (pkl).")
    pickle.dump(res, f)
    
post_to_object_store(cachepath, 
    pickle.dumps(res),
    async=True,
    app=current_app)
```

The good is that I'm reusing the `res` value stored in memory.  Is there a way to leverage the first conversion to pickle?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to write to S3 from the local store directly using the AWS CLI or boto3?

Comment: What tools are you working with? For example, you could run an `aws` command in a non-blocking subprocess if you have the AWS CLI available.

Comment: Great questions.  The process is hosted in a pod running ubuntu/python/flask. I have a boto3 session that in the app context from which I access a ref to a boto client to read/write to S3.  I have full control over the design.  I had not thought of using AWS CLI.

Comment: Well, then you can just use boto3. Create the S3 client, then `s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)`. It's an empirical question whether or not this will be faster than what you have above.